Multiple pacemaker resources failed to start with exitreason='inactive'
I`ve been running HA cluster managed by Pacemaker 2.1.* for a while, and i found a problem as the number of my working tasks (resources) had grown up.
When there are several (lets say 4 or more) pacemaker resources with systemd type, which are supposed to be started at the same time (have no constraint order, or ordered after same single resource), some of them keep failing to start showing the "inactive" error:
Node List:
  * Online: [ test-app-1 test-app-2 ]

Full List of Resources:
  * resParent  (systemd:res_parent):      Started test-app-1
  * resChild1  (systemd:res_child@1):     Stopped
  * resChild2  (systemd:res_child@2):     Stopped
  * resChild3  (systemd:res_child@3):     Stopped
  * resChild4  (systemd:res_child@4):     Started test-app-1
  * resChild5  (systemd:res_child@5):     Started test-app-1
  * resChild6  (systemd:res_child@6):     Started test-app-1
  * resChild7  (systemd:res_child@7):     Started test-app-1

Failed Resource Actions:
  * resChild1_start_0 on test-app-1 'error' (1): call=573, status='complete', exitreason='inactive', last-rc-change='Fri Dec 06 21:34:09 2024', queued=0ms, exec=3620ms
  * resChild2_start_0 on test-app-1 'error' (1): call=572, status='complete', exitreason='inactive', last-rc-change='Fri Dec 06 21:34:08 2024', queued=0ms, exec=3620ms
  * resChild3_start_0 on test-app-1 'error' (1): call=571, status='complete', exitreason='inactive', last-rc-change='Fri Dec 06 21:34:08 2024', queued=0ms, exec=3620ms

All "child" resources have constraint colocation with resParent. Also all of resChild* resources have constraint order to start after resParent. All resources operations has default timeouts.
Actual content of systemd unit is irrelevant to this problem: this could be a simple type unit calling echoes in loop - problem still persists.
As we can see in system logs, pacemaker is requesting to start the resources:
Dec 06 08:32:50 test-app-1 pacemaker-controld[1571]:  notice: Initiating start operation resParent_start_0 locally on test-app-1
Dec 06 08:32:52 test-app-1 pacemaker-controld[1571]:  notice: Result of start operation for resParent on test-app-1: ok
Dec 06 08:32:52 test-app-1 pacemaker-controld[1571]:  notice: Initiating monitor operation resParent_monitor_60000 locally on test-app-1
Dec 06 08:32:52 test-app-1 pacemaker-controld[1571]:  notice: Requesting local execution of monitor operation for resParent on test-app-1
Dec 06 08:32:52 test-app-1 pacemaker-controld[1571]:  notice: Initiating start operation resChild1_start_0 locally on test-app-1
Dec 06 08:32:52 test-app-1 pacemaker-controld[1571]:  notice: Requesting local execution of start operation for resChild1 on test-app-1
Dec 06 08:32:52 test-app-1 pacemaker-controld[1571]:  notice: Initiating start operation resChild2_start_0 locally on test-app-1
Dec 06 08:32:52 test-app-1 pacemaker-controld[1571]:  notice: Requesting local execution of start operation for resChild2 on test-app-1
Dec 06 08:32:52 test-app-1 pacemaker-controld[1571]:  notice: Initiating start operation resChild3_start_0 locally on test-app-1
Dec 06 08:32:52 test-app-1 pacemaker-controld[1571]:  notice: Requesting local execution of start operation for resChild3 on test-app-1
Dec 06 08:32:52 test-app-1 pacemaker-controld[1571]:  notice: Initiating start operation resChild4_start_0 locally on test-app-1
Dec 06 08:32:52 test-app-1 pacemaker-controld[1571]:  notice: Requesting local execution of start operation for resChild4 on test-app-1
Dec 06 08:32:52 test-app-1 pacemaker-controld[1571]:  notice: Initiating start operation resChild5_start_0 locally on test-app-1
Dec 06 08:32:52 test-app-1 pacemaker-controld[1571]:  notice: Requesting local execution of start operation for resChild5 on test-app-1
Dec 06 08:32:52 test-app-1 pacemaker-controld[1571]:  notice: Initiating start operation resChild6_start_0 locally on test-app-1
Dec 06 08:32:52 test-app-1 pacemaker-controld[1571]:  notice: Requesting local execution of start operation for resChild6 on test-app-1
Dec 06 08:32:52 test-app-1 pacemaker-controld[1571]:  notice: Initiating start operation resChild7_start_0 locally on test-app-1
Dec 06 08:32:52 test-app-1 pacemaker-controld[1571]:  notice: Requesting local execution of start operation for resChild7 on test-app-1
Dec 06 08:32:52 test-app-1 pacemaker-controld[1571]:  notice: Result of monitor operation for resParent on test-app-1: ok

After 4 seconds pacemaker reporting the error on start child resources 1, 2, 3:
Dec 06 08:32:56 test-app-1 pacemaker-controld[1571]:  notice: Result of start operation for resChild1 on test-app-1: error (inactive)
Dec 06 08:32:56 test-app-1 pacemaker-controld[1571]:  notice: Result of start operation for resChild2 on test-app-1: error (inactive)
Dec 06 08:32:56 test-app-1 pacemaker-controld[1571]:  notice: Result of start operation for resChild3 on test-app-1: error (inactive)

But shortly after that all child resources units have been started by systemd normally:
Dec 06 08:32:56 test-app-1 systemd[1]: Started Cluster Controlled res_child@3.
°° Subject: A start job for unit res_child@3.service has finished successfully
Dec 06 08:32:56 test-app-1 systemd[1]: Started Cluster Controlled res_child@7.
°° Subject: A start job for unit res_child@7.service has finished successfully
Dec 06 08:32:56 test-app-1 systemd[1]: Started Cluster Controlled res_child@1.
°° Subject: A start job for unit res_child@1.service has finished successfully
Dec 06 08:32:56 test-app-1 systemd[1]: Started Cluster Controlled res_child@5.
°° Subject: A start job for unit res_child@5.service has finished successfully
Dec 06 08:32:56 test-app-1 systemd[1]: Started Cluster Controlled res_child@6.
°° Subject: A start job for unit res_child@6.service has finished successfully
Dec 06 08:32:56 test-app-1 systemd[1]: Started Cluster Controlled res_child@4.
°° Subject: A start job for unit res_child@4.service has finished successfully
Dec 06 08:32:56 test-app-1 systemd[1]: Started Cluster Controlled res_child@2.
°° Subject: A start job for unit res_child@2.service has finished successfully

Resources 4, 5, 6, 7 have been started successfully:
Dec 06 08:32:56 test-app-1 pacemaker-controld[1571]:  notice: Result of start operation for resChild4 on test-app-1: ok
Dec 06 08:32:57 test-app-1 pacemaker-controld[1571]:  notice: Result of start operation for resChild5 on test-app-1: ok
Dec 06 08:32:57 test-app-1 pacemaker-controld[1571]:  notice: Result of start operation for resChild6 on test-app-1: ok
Dec 06 08:32:58 test-app-1 pacemaker-controld[1571]:  notice: Result of start operation for resChild7 on test-app-1: ok

But pacemaker forces "failed" resources to stop:
Dec 06 08:32:58 test-app-1 pacemaker-schedulerd[1570]:  warning: Unexpected result (error: inactive) was recorded for start of resChild1 on test-app-1 at Dec 06 08:32:55 2024
Dec 06 08:32:58 test-app-1 pacemaker-schedulerd[1570]:  warning: Unexpected result (error: failed) was recorded for start of resChild2 on test-app-1 at Dec 06 08:32:55 2024
Dec 06 08:32:58 test-app-1 pacemaker-schedulerd[1570]:  warning: Unexpected result (error: inactive) was recorded for start of resChild3 on test-app-1 at Dec 06 08:32:56 2024
Dec 06 08:32:58 test-app-1 pacemaker-schedulerd[1570]:  warning: resChild1 cannot run on test-app-1 due to reaching migration threshold (clean up resource to allow again)
Dec 06 08:32:58 test-app-1 pacemaker-schedulerd[1570]:  warning: resChild2 cannot run on test-app-1 due to reaching migration threshold (clean up resource to allow again)
Dec 06 08:32:58 test-app-1 pacemaker-schedulerd[1570]:  warning: resChild3 cannot run on test-app-1 due to reaching migration threshold (clean up resource to allow again)
Dec 06 08:32:58 test-app-1 pacemaker-schedulerd[1570]:  notice: Actions: Stop       resChild1      (                           test-app-1 )  due to node availability
Dec 06 08:32:58 test-app-1 pacemaker-schedulerd[1570]:  notice: Actions: Stop       resChild2      (                           test-app-1 )  due to node availability
Dec 06 08:32:58 test-app-1 pacemaker-schedulerd[1570]:  notice: Actions: Stop       resChild3      (                           test-app-1 )  due to node availability

Next i perform cleanup for all resources and all of them staring successfully until next restart.
This issue is described in here: https://lists.clusterlabs.org/pipermail/users/2024-July/036272.html
Apparently, pacemaker is expecting every operation to complete in 2 seconds at maximum.
But when multiple resources is staring at the same time it is not sufficient.
I have edited pacemaker source code (execd_commands.c):
  delay = QB_MIN(2000, delay);  ->  delay = QB_MIN(20000, delay);

With that edition working the problem has gone totally.
Please advise correct solution, as this workaround may have some flaws and should not be used in production.

Problem solution can be found here:
https://bugs.clusterlabs.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5543
